# Django: tracking via signals and cascade delete

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using django signals to track user actions (profile/subscription updates) on site. And have the following models.py:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class Subscription(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', null=True, related_name='subscriptions')
    ...

class Activity(models.Model)
    source = models.ForeignKey('Customer', null=True, related_name='subscriptions')
    ...
```

and following signal:

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Subscription, dispatch_uid='track_sub_post_delete')
def track_subscription_delete(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    extra = {'sub': instance,
             'action': 'deleted',
             'old': instance.__str__()}
    tracker = ActivityTracker(target=instance.customer, mode='subscription', extra=extra)
    tracker.save()
```

When I'm trying to delete any customer/user (on_delete=models.CASCADE):

- all activities are deleted successfully
- activity delete tracker logs it with source = customer
- customer is deleted activity object still has reference on customer (which is already deleted) and this causes django to crush with smth
  like

  ```
  Exception Value: insert or update on table "dashboard_activity" violates foreign key constraint "smth_fk_accounts_source_id"
  DETAIL:  Key (source_id)=(1) is not present in table "dashboard_customers".
  ```

  (can't find exact error msg right now)

Is there any way to prevent this? (other than using on_delete=SET_NULL and manually deleting related objects via signal)